# Open a Pop up window on the click of link on Kendo Grid column

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I want to open a Pop Up window on the click of a link on a Kendo Grid column. The Pop window should contain the detailed data of the current row. Something like given in http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command link. But I want this to work on click of a link of an existing column rather than a new custom button.
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div id="grid" kendo-grid k-options="kendoGrid"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.kendoGrid = myService.getKGrid();
});
```

Service:

```
myApp.service('myService', function () {
this.getKGrid = function () {                
var kGrid = {
       dataSource: [{"Col1":"Val1","Col2":"Val2"}],
       columns: [{
                    field: "Col1",
                    title: "Col1"
                },
                {
                    field: "Col2",
                    title: "Col2",
                    template: "<a href='\\#' class='link' **ng-click='TBD(Open Pop-up window with row details)'**>#=Col2#</a>"
                }                                
            ]
        };
        return kGrid;
    };
});
```

Please guide how to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To start, it looks like that's a modal and not actually a popup in that example, the distinction being that a popup usually refers to an entirely separate window (whole page load). Looks like they're using a "kendo window". I'm not familiar with the framework but [here's the doc page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Yes it would be a pop up Kendo Window containing the data of that row. Also, I want its logic to be in angular Service separated from controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to display the pop up kendo window with row details by making below changes.
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div id="grid" kendo-grid k-options="kendoGrid"></div>

     <div id="details"></div>

        <div id="detailsTemplate" style="display: none;">

                    <div class="row">

                            <text>Data :</text> <text>#=Col1#</text><!--We can add more data here-->
                        </div>
        </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.kendoGrid = myService.getKGrid();
    $scope.showDetails = function (dataItem) {
            myService.showWindow(dataItem);
    } 
});
```

Service:

```
myApp.service('myService', function () {
this.showWindow function () {
                var window = angular.element(details)
                  .kendoWindow({
                      title: "Details",
                      modal: true,
                      visible: false,
                      resizable: false,
                      width: 600
                  }).data("kendoWindow");
                var detailsTemplate = kendo.template(angular.element(detailsTemplate).html());
                window.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
                window.center().open();
            };
this.getKGrid = function () {                
var kGrid = {
       dataSource: [{"Col1":"Val1","Col2":"Val2"}],
       columns: [{
                field: "Col1",
                title: "Col1"
            },
            {
                field: "Col2",
                title: "Col2",
                 template: "<a href='\\#' class='link' ng-click='showDetails(dataItem)'>#=Col2#</a>"
            }                                
        ]
    };
    return kGrid;
  };
});
```